# Tiled and Cocos2D for iPhone: How do you animate tiles?

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone, tiles

I am using v0.6.2 with Cocos2D v0.99.5, and I'm at the point now where I really, really need to animate some of my tiles.  I read [part of a wiki](http://wiki.themanaworld.org/index.php/Mapping_Tutorial) on how to animate tiles but it does not seem to relate to the Mac version, because doesn't have the same features it mentions.

I'm guessing this would involve referring to different parts of a tile atlas interchangeably on a timer in my code, but I'm not sure how this would be done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8227 ?